# Base model in Backbone JS access child data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to create a base model class in Backbone such that all my other models extend this base class. At some point in the base class, I want to be able to access the data set by the extending class.

For example, say my base class is:

```
var baseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    someFunc: function() {
        // This guy needs to operate on 'protected' array set my the extending model
    }
}, {
    protected: [] // this is to be set by the extending model
});

var extendingModel = baseModel.extend({

}, {
    protected: ['id', 'username'];
});
```

can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question!

I will advise you to look into Backbone's [extend](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-230) method wich differs from Underscore's extend.

The second parameter in extend is "static property" so you cannot access it from withing instance method.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvahans/khqd7zfo/10/) is and working fiddle which will provide basic structure.

**Source code**

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    someFunc: function() {
        // This guy needs to operate on 'protected' array set my the extending model
        $('.container').append(JSON.stringify(this.protected || 'something'));
    }
}, {
     // this is to be set by the extending model
});

var ExtendingModel = BaseModel.extend({
  protected: ['id', 'username']
}, {

});

var test = new ExtendingModel();

test.someFunc();


var ExtendingModel2 = BaseModel.extend({
  protected: ['anotherProp', 'ABC']
}, {

});
test1 = new ExtendingModel2();

test1.someFunc();

test3 = new BaseModel();
test3.someFunc();
```